# ADFS 2.0 on 2008 R2 - The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I've been wrestling with a CRM 2013/ADFS 2.0 installation and am at a total loss.

I am getting a redirection error with the link looking like this:

```
https://adfs.network.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2FDatabase.network.local%2Fadfs%2F&wct=2015-01-30T19%3a46%3a32Z&wctx=b18b9a60-e9e5-456c-9fd3-78419cd75029
```

The federationmetadata.xml loads fine.

Anyone have any insights?

Comment: The link above is not a valid wsignin request; wtrealm is missing.

Comment: Redirection URL is not correct. That is why ADFS gives the error. The "wtrealm=EntitID-of-RP" is missing. wreply is no longer enough. I may have been enough back in the ADFS 1.0 time, but not for ADFS 2.0. So either you copied the wrong URL, or something else is wrong, in which case you should add the exception from the eventlog of the ADFS server.

Comment: We reinstalled 2.0 and are now recieving this in the url parameter: `https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fcrm.domain.com%2f&wctx=rm%3d1%26id%3d08e4ee40-929a-45a1-9a8b-66a74a6a74c3%26ru%3d%252fdefault.aspx&wct=2015-02-05T20%3a12%3a11Z&wauth=urn%3afederation%3aauthentication%3awindows`